# Google Maps API v3 Grey Map; marker loaded

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

this is the first time i am working with Google Maps and I have run into an issue.

Instead of loading the map, I get a grey screen. The google icon on the bottom left and the terms of use on the bottom right are loaded.

I have also set a marker, which shows on the map.

I have tried to search for a resolution for many days (using resize, initialising map first, etc...) to no avail. This is my javascript:

```
function startJobMap(){
    var map;
    var marker;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(20.268455824834792,85.84099235520011);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    $("#page_driver_jobdetails").on('pagebeforeshow', initialize);

    function initialize(){
        var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: {lat: 1.290270, lng: 103.851959},
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("driver_jobMap"), mapOptions);

    intializeMarker();
}

var pos = {
    lat: Number(sessionStorage.driverLat),
    lng: Number(sessionStorage.driverLng)
};

function intializeMarker(){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: 1.290270, lng: 103.851959},
        map: map
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    //google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
};
```

This is my HTML

```
<div id="page_driver_jobdetails" data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<a data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-carat-l">Back</a>
    <h1>Job Details</h1>
    </div>
<div class="ui-content">
<div class='ui-grid-b'>
    <div class='ui-block-a'>
    <div id="currentDate"></div>
    </div>
    <div class='ui-block-b'>
    <div id="tyreman"></div>
    </div>
    <div class='ui-block-c'>
    <div id="currentTime"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="driver_jobMap" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div>
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: post your markup, did you put your API KEY?

Comment: yes i did, I have also successfully loaded another google map with geolocation function with the same api key.

Comment: try checking your mapOptions if properties are correct since it might sometimes getting misparsed by google API and FYI, it's actually working fine on my end. check your console if you got any error

Comment: thanks roljhon for your replies. there isn't any error message in the console, though when i use google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); as suggested by another resolution i searched it did give me 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined

Comment: how are you calling your `startJobMap` function? and try to regenerate your api key.

Comment: with this:
$(function(){
 $("#page_driver_home").on('pagebeforecreate', startMap);
 $("#page_driver_jobdetails").on('pagebeforecreate', startJobMap);
});

Comment: Check if you have problems with css styles. An overflow:hidden   in #driver_jobMap could be causing this problem

Comment: `$("#page_driver_jobdetails").on('pagebeforecreate', startJobMap); });` this is a unexpected token error on `}`. this is not showing on your console? maybe you're not firing it. will you show us your code on that?

Comment: @Fran I am using jquery mobile 1.4.5 for css, could that be a reason why?

Comment: @Roljhon no i do not have that error for that. this is all the code i have used other than the jquery mobile files i have linked in the header

Comment: @bingyuantay oops, didn't notice the it was wrappred inside a function call, nvm that, anyway, try regenerating your API KEY.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  The posted code doesn't run, if I add the code from the comments that "calls" it, I get a javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: startMap is not defined`

Comment: @geocodezip my apologies, please use this code to run the function:
$(function(){ $("#page_driver_jobdetails").on('pagebeforecreate', startJobMap); });

Comment: @Roljhon I have regenerated my api key and inserted the newly generated one, the issue remains the same

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue; I did not realise that jQuery required the function to be called after the page has been loaded.

I have followed the resolution as provided in this article here:

http://www.gajotres.net/using-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-with-jquery-mobile/

My apologies for leaving out that i am using jquery mobile, i did not think the issue lied there.